# Google analytics integration with postgresql using python, table doesn't populate

Tags: python, postgresql, google-analytics, psycopg2

I'm trying to upload my Google Analytics data into my postgres database using Python, however, I encountered a problem which I don't really know how to solve, being very new to Python.

First I used a code to fetch one dimension and two metrics using psycopg2 :

```
if traffic_results.get('rows', []):
   for row in traffic_results.get('rows'):
     #print(row)
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO traffic (yearMonth, users, sessions)
                    VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", [row[0], row[1], row[2]])
else:
  print('No Rows Found')
```

This worked fine, however after creating a new table "traffic1" and trying to return data with more dimension and metrics it prints the "No Rows Found"

```
 if traffic_results.get('rows', []):
   for row in traffic_results.get('rows'):
     #print(row)
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO traffic0 (campaign, device, impressions, clicks, ctr)
                       VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]])
 else:
   print('No Rows Found')
```

I'd appreciate any hints on what could be wrong. Thank you.

EDIT This is the full code I'm using:

```
import psycopg2  
import sys

from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError  
from googleapiclient import sample_tools  
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials  
from httplib2 import Http  
from apiclient.discovery import build

#Main
def main():  
  # Authenticate and create the service for the Core Reporting API
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'xxxxxx.json', 
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])
  http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
  service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http_auth)

  # Define the connection string and connect
  conn_string = "xxx' port=xxx
dbname='GA' user='admin' password='password'"
  conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

  # Open a cursor
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  # Run the query function using the API service
  traffic_results = get_api_traffic_query(service).execute()

  # Insert each row of the result set
  if traffic_results.get('rows', []):
    for row in traffic_results.get('rows'):
      #print(row)
      cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO traffic0 (campaign, device, impressions, clicks, ctr)
                    VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]])
  else:
    print('No Rows Found')

  # Commit changes
  conn.commit()

  # Select and retrieve results
  #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM traffic0")
  #records = cursor.fetchall()
  #print(records)

  # Close the cursor and the connection
  cursor.close()
  conn.close()

# Query function
 def get_api_traffic_query(service):  
  return service.data().ga().get(
    ids='ga:xxxxxx',
    start_date='2017-01-01',
    end_date='2017-01-31',
    metrics='ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,ga:CTR',
    dimensions='ga:campaign,ga:deviceCategory',
 #    sort='-ga:yearMonth',
 #    filters='ga:pagePath=~signup',

 segment='sessions::condition::ga:hostname!~mongo|app|help|docs|staging|googleweblight',
    start_index='1',
    max_results='25')

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  main()
```

Comment: What is `traffic_results`? It looks like a dictionary. Please provide the code that is used to define/create it. Also please, fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

```
if traffic_results.get('rows', []):
```

is `False` and therefore `else:` clause body is executed. This implies that there's no key `rows` in the response from Google Analytics or it is an empty list. Examine the response (even by printing it to stdout) and check what keys are present and if the response doesn't contain error by any chance.

Comment: Thank you, it does appear that the response brings back an empty list, which I don't understand because using googles Query Explorer the same Dimensions and Metrics bring back normal results.

Comment: Double check with Analytics documentation if you are querying the metrics correctly.